# error when trying to apply a linq query to a list that i have as a result of another lin

Tags: c#, linq, nullreferenceexception

I am trying get filter some data that i have got.
At first, data is brought as the following:

```
List<task> method1(){    
return context.Tasks.where(x => x.date < Datetime.Today()).Tolist();
}
```

then i try to do the following:

```
void method2(){
List<task> tasks1 = method1();
}
```

till now I have filled the list of tasks with 6 records as shown by debugger. But when I try to linq this list I get a nullreferenceexception> tasks1 is a list of 6 tasks.

```
List<Task> tasks2 = tasks1.where(x => x.something.Equals("123")).tolist();
```

To debug and dive deeper, I tried to separate code as follows:

```
var q = tasks1.where(x => x.something.Equals("123"));
  List<Task> tasks2 = q.tolist();
```

when debugging I found the following data in

> q:  {  current = null,
>       non-public-members: {
>                     current = ...,
>                     enumerator= ...,
>                     predicate= ...,
>                     .....and a little more fields,
>                 }    }

why is this error?
and how to fix it?

Comment: Please share the `inner exception message` too.

Comment: `x.something` must be null.

Comment: Sorry, but i am copying my code from another computer.

Comment: Is the question clear now?

Comment: Innerexception is null

Comment: Just change `tasks1.where(x => x.something.Equals("123"))` to `tasks1.where(x => x.something == "123")`

Comment: thank you all, It is the correct answer @Justin, but in fact  I need to apply two conditions with or in between them. tasks1.where(x => (x.something == "123") OR x.something.startsWith("123") ). and then i am facing the same problem

Comment: `[NULL].Equals(` will  raise a `NullReferenceException` because a null object has no methods that could be called, it is not an instance. On the other hand `[null property] == value` will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the code that you have shared, the only cause of null reference exception can be calling the method of `Equals` on a null property int this part:

```
Where(x => x.something.Equals("123"))
```

meaning that the `something` property of at least one item in the list is `null`.  
You have different ways of handling this, one of which could be:

```
Where(x => x.something != null && x.something.Equals("123"))
```

Comment: Or x.property == value